# How to hide iframe src link

Tags: html, iframe

I have the following iframe code in a topic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://whatever.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to hide the iframe src link? I don't want users to see the iframe source code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: exactly how could the browser go fetch the contents of that iframe to display to the user if you don't provide the address of the content? unless you yourself proxy that content through your server, you **HAVE** to send the src attribute to the client, which means they can view it themselves.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anyway to hide the iframe src link?

No.

> I don't want users to see the iframe source code.

Sorry, then you shouldn't be including this iframe at all.

Tools like FireBug would make it extremely easy to analyze the network traffic and see exactly which site the HTML is accessing. So no matter how hard you try to obfuscate your code, bury it under a ton of compressed, minified and God knows what other javascript that dynamically generates and injects this iframe into the DOM, simply by looking at the [Network tab of FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/network) the client will be able to immediately see the exact HTTP request you have made.

Comment: But is there any other way of linking a page into a topic like the iframe and hide the source? .

Comment: No, there isn't. You cannot hide the source of something you have already sent to the client browser.

Answer (score 1):

I found a node.js npm plugin that can hide any src="*" also content+href - easy to use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

This works also for php href, src, content it will use everything inside src=""

You need only node.js for creating the exported files. It´s easy to use even if you don´t know node.js. You can watch youtube guides for installing and using node.js
If you create enviroment 1 time you can load cool stuff with npm

It turns

```
<script src="test/folder/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

into

```
<script src="TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq" rel="stylesheet">
```

And it generate new jquery include codes like this to include your scripts with javascript in a external file

```
$('[src=\'TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR\']').attr("src", "test/folder/sample.js")  
$('[href=\'gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq\']').attr("src", "test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css")
```

Also I would suggest you that you include all of your external javascript codes in 1 single js file. This file you place in the root of your index file that you can make this

```
<script src="./allinone_external_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then make right htaccess that nobody can acces this file. You can also make a fake import script for the source code that every body can see. But this file is only a redirect for the real external js file. you make this multiple times as example + use other obfuscation tools. This will protect you from people searching exploits with your javascript codes. I know its no big deal and maybe you can see the jquery include codes if you know how. But anyway its a great protection.